# How can I put a title above a 2 column page

Tags: titles, two-column

I just want a standard title then commence a 2 column page - but when I use this code it puts it all on the next page (as it inserts a newpage). How can I un-insert the new page OR put the title in in another way.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
 \begin{document}.


\twocolumn[{%
 \centering
 \LARGE The Title \\[1.5em]
 \large Author: Anton van der Vegt\\[1em]
 \normalsize
}]`enter code here`
```

Comment: This could be because you have a `.` immediately following `\begin{document}`. Remove that and you'll be golden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{Anton van der Vegt}
\date{}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to format differently the title, it works without problems:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{%
 \centering
 \LARGE The Title\\[1.5em]
 \large Author: Anton van der Vegt\\[1em]
}]

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: put your glasses on, and look again at the op's mwe and @werner's comment.  *that* is the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy with the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}.

\begin{strip}%
 \centering
 \LARGE The Title \\[1.5em]
 \large Author: Anton van der Vegt\\[1em]
 \normalsize
\end{strip}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]